# Edited CSS isn't overwriting original theme CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I am adding custom CSS to a wordpress theme (www.ronanmart.in) to get the effect I want.

For the .hero-inner div on the homepage, I am trying to edit the padding however it seems to keep defaulting to the theme settings. Anything else I've edited has overwritten the theme CSS.

Original padding:

```
padding: 121px 2em;
```

New padding:

```
padding: 261px 2em 0 2em;
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you used the same specificity?

Comment: Is your CSS-file included after the theme CSS-file?

Comment: Do you have same or higher rule priority for `.hero-inner`?

Comment: If I look at your website, it IS being applied. (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you write a more specific CSS rule:

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed of different sorts of CSS selectors.
>   **source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

For a quick test you can use `!important` first to see the rules are matching. If the element is styled expected **you should remove** `!important` and try to write a more specific rule.

```
.class-name {
    padding: 261px 2em 0 2em !important;
}

/* the same rule, more specific */
div .parent-class .class-name {
    padding: 261px 2em 0 2em;
}
```

> **Note:** You should avoid using `!important`!

Answer (score 0):

```
padding: top.px right.px bottom.px left.px;
```

so

```
padding: top and bottom.px AND left and right.px;
```

If you just write two properties it is applied to top/bottom and left/write the same time .
I assume you think writing two properties will follow top/right, but its top/bottom and left/write